# How do I disable then enter even using jquery version 1.2.6 in IE

Tags: jquery, keydown, unbind

I am new to JavaScript, and I am repairing a bug from someone else's code. My question is that every time a user on the form presses the enter key on a text box it triggers a windows.confirm "messagevar confirm = window.confirm('Remove Design Check Date?')";, what I believe is happening is that there is an event handler being captured when the form loads which triggers the calendar.

Here is the original code:

```
$jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
$('printableDesignLog').hide();
$('add').hide();
$('orders_Input').hide();
$('newOrder_div').hide();
$('designLog_Details').hide();
$('jobNumber').focus();

getDesigners();
new Ajax.Autocompleter("jobNumber","jobNumbers", 
baseURL + "search.php?task=getJobNumbers_WithSeparator",{
     minChars: 2,
     frequency: 0.1,
indicator: 'indicator',
afterUpdateElement : setJobNumber});

Date.format = 'mmm dd, yyyy';
$j(function(){
$j('#Design_Date')
   .datePicker({createButton:true, startDate:'Jan 01, 2006',        
    endDate:'Dec 31, 2015'})
   .bind('click', function(){               
$j(this).dpDisplay();
    this.blur();
    return false;
    })
    .dpSetOffset(-50, 20) // Move calender just above/right
    .bind('dateSelected', function(e, selectedDate, $td){
 $('DesignDate').value = selectedDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
    });

    });
 $j(function(){
 $j('#FollowUp_Dt')
    .datePicker({createButton:true, startDate:'Jan 01, 2010', endDate:'Dec 31, 2015'})
    .bind('click', function(){              
 $j(this).dpDisplay();
     this.blur();
     return false;
     })
    .dpSetOffset(-150, -150) // move calendar above the button to the left
    .bind('dateSelected', function(e, selectedDate, $td){
 $('FollowUpDt').value = selectedDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
     });
     });

     });
```

Below is the code that I tried. I tried to disable the enter key event as it is not needed in this form, I am using javascript prototype version '1.6.0.2', and jquery version 1.2.6 but when I enter the below code it doesn't recognise keydown, and it outputs the following error in IE "Unable to get property 'keydown' of undefined or null reference". Thank you for your assistance.

```
function preventDefault() {
   var e = this.originalEvent;

   this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;
   if ( !e ) {
       return;
 }

 [// If preventDefault exists, run it on the original event]
     if ( e.preventDefault ) {
     e.preventDefault();

 [// Support: IE]
 [// Otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false]
} else {
      e.returnValue = false;
      }
      }


jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input[type=text]').keydown(function(event){
    if (event.which == 13){
        $('input[type=text]').unbind();
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 });
```

Here is the code for the windows.confirm message box that keeps coming up

```
function removeDesignCheckDate(id)
{
j( ".JQCancelSubmit" ).keypress(function(event) {
    var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (code == 13) { //Enter
            return false;
        }
});

var confirm = window.confirm('Remove Design Check Date?') ;
//confirm.blur();
if (!confirm) return ;
var jobNumber = $j('#jobNumber').val() ;
var tmp = id.split('-',2);//split to 0:- field name & 1:- DesignOrderID
//$j('#msg').html(tmp[0] + ' | ' + tmp[1] + ' > '+ $j('#'+id).val());
//i.e. tmp[0] is the field name; tmp[1] is the DesignOrderID

//construct data object:
var d = new Object(); 
d[eval('"'+tmp[0]+'"')] = $j('#' + id).val(); 
var data = Object.toJSON(d);

var callback = function(response){
    if (response.error) { // display error
       $(id).focus();
 $j('#msg').html('check your input ...');
 setTimeout("$('msg').innerHTML = ''", 3000);//reset the result after 10sec
 }else {
 $j('#msg').html('Changes Saved ...');
//$j(id).html('') ;
refreshAfterDelete(jobNumber); 
setTimeout("$j('#msg').html('')", 3000);//reset the result after 10sec
(tmp[0]).match('Date') ? updateDaysToDesignCompletion(tmp[1]) : '';
}
};
$j.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: controller, 
    data: 'task=removeDesignCheckDate' + '&DesignOrderID=' + tmp[1] + 
         '&dummy=' + new Date().getTime(),
    success: callback
});

}
```

Comment: `$` isn't jquery in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
 $('body').on('keypress', '.JQCancelSubmit', function (event) {
                var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (code == 13) { //Enter
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Put the css class 'JQCancelSubmit' on your input that you whant cancel submit

**Edit 1**

```
or for previus versions this may work:

$('.JQCancelSubmit').bind('keypress',function(event){

  var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                    if (code == 13) { //Enter
                        return false;
                    }
})
```

**Edit 2**

you could try this

```
$( ".JQCancelSubmit" ).keypress(function(event) {
       var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                        if (code == 13) { //Enter
                            return false;
                        }
});

Edit 3
```

function removeDesignCheckDate (id){

/// your code;
}

Comment: It doesn't recognize the bind event handler, got an error message " Unable to get property 'bind' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: @user2946461 Strange, because bind exists from jq versions earlier than 1.2.6 . See my edit please

Comment: Even with the revised code it is still out putting the error message "Unable to get property 'bind' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: resolved that error but now its still displaying windows.confirm message when when a user presses the enter key on a text box

Comment: sorry about this but what I meant to say was it was displaying a windows.confirm message "messagevar confirm = window.confirm('Remove Design Check Date?')" when someone presses the enter key on a text box.

Comment: @user2946461 did you put the css class on the input that you want to cancel submission ? see this http://jsfiddle.net/DcFd7/12/

Comment: @Scandcar I did I put the css class name in the very top function of this page in the "$jQuery(document).ready(function(){" function and it had no effect it is still outputting a dialog box "Remove Design Order Date ?" with an "OK" or "Cancel" button, I even put this code in where the windows.confirm dialog box is placed and changed the code to

Comment: $j( "input[type=text]" ).keypress(function(event) {
        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (code == 13) { //Enter
                return false;
                   }
    });  

To remove the enter key event from all textboxes with no result

Comment: @user2946461 I do not understand what is 'J' in your context. may be in conflict suppose ..
Never less, the event has to be out of function removeDesignCheckDate to work, I suppose